# Big sized main is going to make program slow?

Tags: c

If I have main function with, say 10K lines. Is it going to run slow that having a 4 functions with 2.5k lines? Or the functions are only for aesthetic reasons like code clarity etc?

Comment: Not per se, but meta reasoning suggests that anyone writing a 10k-loc function probably didn't write the highest-quality code to begin with.

Comment: You might find it interesting to run a tool like [Atomiq](http://getatomiq.com/) and find out just how many DRY violations are in those large functions.

Answer (score 12):

A single function won't have any function calling overhead, which is infinitesimally small on modern hardware, whereas a solution with four functions will incur function calling penalties.

However, the next person to maintain your code will hunt you down and kill you for having either a single 10K line function or four 2.5K line functions.

Functions are supposed to:

- Perform a single unit of work and have a single responsibility;
- Eradicate code repetition;
- Modularise code.

How many of those 10K lines are the same lines copy-and-pasted over and over?

Comment: +1.  I know I had murder in my heart when my team was tasked with speeding up a program that had a 5K-line `main` with no less than 13 `goto`s.  Code was so brittle that *any* attempt to modify would break it.  Code for correctness first, maintainability second, and speed...somewhere after that.

Answer (score 5):

It will run more slowly, because the code is going to wind up being so ridiculously convoluted and horrible to maintain that there will undoubtedly be errors that will grind it to a screeching halt at run time.

Answer (score 3):

You should make yours this advice from Linux kernel coding style:

> "Functions should be short and sweet, and do just one thing. They should
>   fit on one or two screenfuls of text (the ISO/ANSI screen size is 80x24,
>   as we all know), and do one thing and do that well."

http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle

Answer (score 0):

Just imagine a scenario where you want to build a big building, and you got to do the whole work alone... it would be easy for you to know what you are doing. But when you stop working on the building and some other person is appointed to do the job... he'll be in hell...

Similarly, doing your job alone would just help you take enough time. Rather appoint new members in your group and let them do the work for you...

Coming back to the technicalities, using functions, your code will be easy to read, maintainable and good chances of making lesser size of the compiled exe.

And as always, you can call a same function again and again instead of rewriting the same code multiple times in a module.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. In theory, putting all that code into a single function will reduce function call overhead. On a modern processor with decently written code, that's usually pretty low to start with though.

In the other direction, there's a pretty fair chance that a single function that size  will make relatively poor use of the cache. Unlike function call overhead, cache usage frequently *is* a pretty serious consideration. A reference to main memory will typically be at least 15-20 times slower than a reference to cache, so even a fairly small improvement in cache usage can improve speed quite a bit.

Given that imbalance between the two, chances are pretty good that breaking it up into smaller functions with more careful factoring will improve speed.